# Wifi cannot find available networks

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I was facing some issue where wifi is losing internet access within few minutes after connecting. So I did a driver update with driver update software and it update the atheros wifi driver. Still I was facing same issues. So, I downloaded wifi driver from sony website and installed it. After that when I switch on wifi, I cannot find any networks. Also vaio smart network won't let me switch on the wifi but I can switch on bluetooth. So I have found some more related wifi drivers from other sites and installed them after uninstalling existing ones.
I have also uninstalled smart network program in between and reinstalled to see if it is causing the problem.

[image]

I have tried system restore but computer is unable to do that.
I have tried installing the driver provided by sony website but still same issue.
Model : VPCEB36FG.
How can I make my laptop wifi work?
Please help me. I am not interested to reinstall my OS.
Btw, does OS installers have wifi driver or should we install it after OS installation?

Answer (score 0):

Okay first,make sure ur wifi is enabled.by pressing fn button + any f button(in my case it f12)

second try driverpack solution to make sure u having a correct driver.find that at google